# Jenkins Pipeline: git-lfs: command not found

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have got a Jenkins Pipeline Job configured to run a script from Git version control. I have given a repository path but it failing at checkout with git lfs command not found.

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 0dac40f9a4f8908d177e319b2742908018663eb1" returned status code 128:
    stdout: 
    stderr: git-lfs smudge -- 'testlfs.txt': git-lfs: command not found
    error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed -1
    error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
    fatal: testlfs.txt: smudge filter lfs failed


    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2372)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$1000(CliGitAPIImpl.java:80)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
    Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 0dac40f9a4f8908d177e319b2742908018663eb1
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2705)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1195)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I resolve this issue? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

This is bug reported [JENKINS-52857](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52857) and workaround was created manually link

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/git-lfs /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/libexec/git-core/git-lf
```

Comment: I am new to git and jenkins can you tell me what to do with this command

Comment: Review this installation steps [Git LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who need a little help getting the solution given by @sercheo_87 to work, here is a more detailed explanation.

If you type `git --exec-path` git will tell you the path that it searches to find the other "core" git sub programs installed on your box, one of which is `git-lfs`. For me, this is what it told me:

```
$ git --exec-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core
```

So that means that git will look for `git-lfs` inside that folder. The problem was that for me, there was no copy of `git-lfs` there. So the solution was to find where it was currently installed and create a simlink to `git-lfs` inside `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core`.

```
$ readlink -f `which git-lfs`
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git-lfs/3.4.0/bin/git-lfs
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/git-lfs/3.4.0/bin/git-lfs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core
```

Then jenkins was able to download the git repo.